# How do I get IDE code completion to work with JSF 2.2 non-composite component attributes?

Tags: jsf-2

**Problem:** I get code completion on the tags but not the attributes.

I am working on a new web application using

- Java 8
- JSF 2.2.14
- PrimeFaces 6.1
- Netbeans 8.2

We are using a library that is provided to us in JavaScript (generated from Typescript sources). I have written a **non-composite component** to wrap this library and keep all that JavaScript code hidden and in one place. It initializes the the library and provides attributes to pass JavaScript callback functions to the library (so we still have to write *some* JavaScript).

**snippet from the JSF .xhtml file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function jscallbackHandler() { alert("function called!");}
</script>

<myComponent:initialize callback1="jscallbackHandler" />
```

This tag invokes my class to write a lot of JavaScript into the page to setup and initialize the library.

I am using the **@FacesComponent** annotation to declare my classes as custom components.

**snippet from 'InitMyComponent.java' file**

```
@FacesComponent(createTag = true,
    tagName = "initialize",
    namespace = "https://com.my.project/myComponent",
    value = InitMyComponent.FAMILY)
public class InitMyComponent extends UIComponentBase { ... }
```

This is working except for IDE code completion and I can't find documentation or examples for JSF 2.2 components that show how to declare attributes and hook them into the project.  I have seen many examples of earlier JSF 2.x components that use a taglib.xml to define the attributes for code completion, but it seems to be 'at odds' with features of the JSF 2.2 style annotation. I have to remove most of the attributes of the annotation (basically revert to a JSF 2.0 style annotation) or I get "**Expression Error: Named Object ... not found**". I have also gotten **Tag Library supports namespace, but no tag was defined for name**. If I just provide a component name to the annotation that matches the one in the taglib file it works, but just no code completion.

I have a FACELETS_LIBRARIES name/value pair in a context-param tag in the web.xml to declare where my facelet-taglib file is located.

**snippet from the 'web.xml' file**

```
<!-- Enable IDE autocompletion on component attributes -->
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/myComponent.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have a facelet-taglib file named 'myComponent.taglib.xml' in my WEB-INF directory (same place as faces-config.xml and web.xml).

UPDATE: Responding to the comment by Kukeltje, I updated my facelet-taglib file to version 2.2, but I still get "No Suggestions" from my IDE... also updated the namespaces in my .xhtml JSF source file (even though this site said the older versions were still supported 
https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/jsf22-namespaces/)

**snippet from the 'myComponent.taglib.xml' file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">

<namespace>http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components</namespace>
<composite-library-name>myComposites</composite-library-name>

<namespace>https://com.my.project/myComponent</namespace>
<tag>
  <tag-name>initialize</tag-name>
    <component>
      <component-type>InitMyComponent</component-type>
    </component>
    <attribute>
        <name>callback1</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

**The faces-config.xml file** - defines the javaee and schema namespaces, and version 2.2 but it is otherwise 'empty'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
  version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

I am fine with having to type in all the attributes but I just can't seem to find the proper way to hook this feature into my project.

Note: I have experimented with using a composite component. The code completion for attributes worked, but then I lost code completion for the tags. I'm just writing out JavaScript to setup and call a JavaScript library's initialize function but also, I would really love to pass a JavaScript object back to a bean on the server when my callback function is invoked. I am currently using a [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) provided solution that involves p:remoteCommand and updating hidden input fields. I would greatly prefer to provide reference to the bean using EL in an attribute of my custom component.

Comment: Tried with creating a '2.2' versioned taglib?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, I updated the taglib file to 2.2 as you suggested, and also the namespaces in my JSF file, but it still doesn't give me code completion.

Comment: I deleted the note about how to write JavaScript into the page with a composite component since I realized I could with the script tag. I can do most of what I'm currently doing with a composite component, and I get code completion on the attributes, but now I lose code completion of the tag names.  I can use the composite component as a 'wrapper' for the non-composite component, if just to get code completion of attributes, but it's an ugly and incomplete hack since code completion doesn't work on the tag. Help!

Comment: What is Your IDE btw? Tried another one? Might very well be an IDE issue... Please try (if possible) with a different IDE.

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion, since the topic is one of IDE integration. However, I just tested this, and in this IDE, which is Netbeans 8.2, both PrimeFaces 6.1 and OmniFaces 2.6.8 give me tag and attribute completion.  I will give it a try anyway, with another IDE, just to see if I actually have it working in something else and Netbeans doesn't get it. Thanks :)

Comment: Update for composite components: I updated my facelet-taglib with a namespace/composite-library-name tag pair and I got tag completion for the composite components. Although it's less than hoped for, I can wrap the non-composite components with a short composite file to get my code completion, for now.